# How to draw underline for string which contains only space using DrawString?

Tags: c#, msdn

I have faced underline missing issue with if I only draw text (only spaces) with underline style. Please refer the below tried code at my end and let me know the solution to resolve this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(400, 200);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 400, 200);
System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Underline);
brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
stringformat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
string text = "Hello";
SizeF sizeF = m_graphics.MeasureString(text, font, new PointF(0, 0), stringformat);
graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, new RectangleF(0, 0, sizeF.Width, sizeF.Height), stringformat);
text = "     ";
float width = sizeF.Width;
sizeF = m_graphics.MeasureString(text, font, new PointF(0, 0), stringformat);
graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, new RectangleF(width, 0, sizeF.Width, sizeF.Height), stringformat);
text = "World";
width += sizeF.Width;
sizeF = m_graphics.MeasureString(text, font, new PointF(0, 0), stringformat);
graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, new RectangleF(width, 0, sizeF.Width, sizeF.Height), stringformat);
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question. Currently it's not a question at all, just a code dump.

Comment: Hi Zohar,
Underline missing while draw string which contains only space using DrawString. So, i have asked question regarding to that and given tried code at my end.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. You are asking for other people's time and effort for free, the least you can do is make it as easy as possible for them to help you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see you have three options:

1. Use a **monospaced** font (*Courier New* and *Lucida Sans Typewriter*). More info on the monospaced fonts [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/90057/microsoft-supplied-monospaced-truetype-fonts).

   ```
   System.Drawing.Font font = 
                       new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Underline);
   ```
2. **Write the text at once**. If you only write the spaces then the method won't work, even if you use `TextRenderer` to draw the string. So if you receive the strings separately then I suggest add them in a `StringBuilder` and draw the whole text or sentence.

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("Hello");
   sb.Append("     ");
   sb.Append("World!");        

   var bitmap = new Bitmap(400, 200);
   var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
   Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
   graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 400, 200);            
   var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Underline);
   brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
   var stringformat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
   stringformat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
   stringformat.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
   var text = sb.ToString();                          
   var sizeF = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, new PointF(0, 0), stringformat);
   graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, 
                        new RectangleF(5, 0, sizeF.Width, sizeF.Height), stringformat);
   ```
3. **The hack version**: You can draw an invisible character such as `(char)127` which is the delete character, like this (you can use the code from point 2 and add this line when initializing the `StringBuilder`):

   ```
   sb.Append(new string ((char)127, 5)); //this will create approx. five spaces.
   ```

   You can use other invisible characters if you need.

The 3rd options is a hack and should be considered as such, I would recommend option 1 if you can change the font otherwise option 2.

Comment: Hi Mihali,

Thank you for your update.

Is there any possibility to meet my requirement?. Either Option 1 for all fonts or Option 2 for string "Hello   ".

Because i'm using default fonts (not monospaced) such as "Arial" or "Times New Roman" or etc.,
and below text (ends with space) alone as used for draw string.
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hello");
sb.Append("     ");

Can you please update me on this?

Comment: You need to use Option 2 and 3 for the trailing spaces. You can also replace the space with an invisible char and you should have the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

If i replace with some invisible char for spaces (trailing), then the retrieving text which is drawn will not be equal to the given input text. i.e. SPACE char not equals that invisible (any) char.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Unfortunately this will be difficult to achieve without a monospaced font. You would have to measure on invisible char and the width of the space character and paint every invisible char individualy with the width of the space for the font you choose.